# Use Drop Down Menu to change cells next to the drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, list

I am very new at vba and am interested in creating a program that does the following.
When a item is selected from a drop down menu it will paste certain text into the cells that are next to the drop down list selected.

For example:
My drop down list contains in column A
COMMENT
MOVE

When I select "COMMENT" I would like to populate in column B "ENTER COMMENT"
When I select "MOVE" I would like to populate in Column B "ENTER MOVE TYPE" and in Column C "ENTER MOVE SPEED"

I would only like these to change upon selecting the drop down menu as to I am using this data in cells other cells based upon which drop down menu item is selected.

Comment: How many items are in your dropdown list? There are a number of possible approaches here, getting a sense of size will help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you could do this with either VBA or just a function.
In my example, I have a list in `A1` and in `A4` Both containing "COMMENT" and "MOVE".

[image]

In `B1` I have the function `=IF(A1="MOVE","ENTER MOVE TYPE",IF(A1="COMMENT","ENTER COMMENT"," "))`

And in `C1` the function `=IF(A1="MOVE","ENTER MOVE SPEED","")`

For the list in `A4` I'm using VBA on the worksheet (right click the sheet and select "show code")

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A4")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.Value2 = "MOVE" Then
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "ENTER MOVE TYPE"
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "ENTER MOVE SPEED"
    ElseIf Target.Value2 = "COMMENT" Then
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "ENTER COMMENT"
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = ""
    Else
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = ""
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = ""
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I'm using a relative position of the text in `B` and `C` with the help of `.Offset` so less code needs to be changed depending on list location.

Comment: You have almost achieve OP's need but I think the whole should be restrict to one Cell in Column A instead of A1 & A4.

Comment: @RajeshS It's just to showcase two different ways of doing it at once. Doesn't really work to have both on the same cell, so he should pick one and use it in whatever cell he needs.